# mstile image location specification

Tags: xml, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I am implementing a site where keeping browserconfig.xml at the root of it is inconvenient and hard-coding the tile images location inside the  element to a server-relative path is also undesirable, but it appears that's the only way Windows 8.1 interprets this [specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ie/dn455106).

My master page has the following html snippet:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="msapplication-config" content="/config/browserconfig.xml" />
</head>
<body> ...</body>
</html>
```

the browserconfig.xml has to use server-relative paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<browserconfig>
  <msapplication>
    <tile>
      <square70x70logo src="/images/mstile-70x70.png"/>
      <square150x150logo src="/images/mstile-150x150.png"/>
      <wide310x150logo src="/images/mstile-310x150.png"/>
      <square310x310logo src="/images/mstile-310x310.png"/>
      <TileColor>#ffffff</TileColor>
    </tile>
  </msapplication>
</browserconfig>
```

Anyone else is encountering this sort of behavior?
From common sense perspective i would think the src property should take paths relative to the browsercofnig.xml file as well, but it appears not to be the case.

Comment: IE/Edge's fondness for the root directory is very annoying. I've tried moving the XML somewhere else via `msapplication-config`, it seems to be complicated: [this solution](https://github.com/RealFaviconGenerator/realfavicongenerator/issues/272#issuecomment-244302392) contradicts [these docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn320426(v=vs.85).aspx) ("relative references ... are presumed to be located in the same directory as the configuration file itself", but, get this: "For best results, use absolute (fully-qualified) paths."... Duh.)

Comment: FWIW, I fell back to using `msapplication-TileImage` (with`msapplication-TileColor`), which worked as expected and I didn't have to dynamically generate the `browserconfig.xml`. No idea how safe this is, as the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255024(v=vs.85).aspx#msapplication-TileImage) are kinda wonky: contradicting notes, a *backslash in the path*... oh geez.

Answer (score 2):

at http://www.buildmypinnedsite.com/en

a requirement is that your browserconfig file must be located in your site root folder.

assuming that you are placing the pinned site meta on your site landing page (located in the web root)

then content="browserconfig.xml" should work as expected.

Comment: I saw that site and indeed, and saw that requirement, but according to MSDN specicification "msapplication-config" meta attribute does accept custom paths for the browsercofnig.xml and i am able to use it.  My issue is with the src attributes inside the file.